# Ordering two columns, avoiding skip to new line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a page that shows a label and the corresponding text (might be multi-line), but I do not get the lines from the label and the text in the same line.

HTML Code:

```
<label for='name'>Name:</label>
<div class='input' id='name'> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
</div>
<label>Date:</label>
<div class='input' id='date'> 10.10.2012 </div>

<label>Sum:</label>
<div class='input' id='sum'>ABC </div>
```

CSS:

```
label {

width:150px
float: left;

}

.input{
margin-left:150px
}
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EfaRA/2/) Link

Comment: You missed a semi colon after `width: 150px`. Fix that and all is grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost in your style `;` after `width:150px`

Try this: [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/izijeh/1/edit)

```
label {
  width:150px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon `;` is missing after `width:150px`

Correct it. It works

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EfaRA/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

Missing  ";" after 150px and clear:both after div

```
   label {
        width:150px;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        border: 1px solid red;   
    }
    .input{
        margin-left:150px;
    }

    br {
       display: block;
       clear: both;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DGolub/msvVc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.input{
  display:inline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `display:block;` in `.input`:

```
.input{
margin-left:150px;
display: block;
}
```